# React TypeError: React.renderComponent is not a function

Tags: reactjs, render

I've got this weird message after following a React tutorial building a simple app.
http://blog.revathskumar.com/2014/05/getting-started-with-react.html

I used bower to install react and included the scripts like so:

```
<script src="bower_components/react/react.js"></script>
<script src="bower_components/react/JSXTransformer.js"></script>
```

as in the tutorial.
At first I thought the scripts weren't loaded but that's obviously not the case.
What is the problem?

Answer (score 23):

These days it is

```
ReactDOM.render(
```

and include the source file:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.0/react-dom.js"></script>
```

This is the warning from React:

```
Warning: React.render is deprecated. Please use ReactDOM.render from require('react-dom') instead.
```

Answer (score 17):

bower installs the latest version in this case version 0.12.0.

there is a change in the render function convention.

https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2014/10/28/react-v0.12.html

> Component has been removed from all of our React.render* methods.

so use

```
    React.render(
```

instead of

```
   React.renderComponent(
```

Comment: Actually it installs 0.13.x currently. If it was 0.12.x that version only deprecated the function without removing it, but .13 removed it.

Answer (score 7):

Lately 'React.render()' is depreciated So use  'ReactDom.render()'

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDom from 'react-dom';
import App from './components/App.jsx';
require('./main.scss');

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('container'));
```

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem; I followed the tutorial precisely and I got the same error you did.

These are the changes I needed to make to get it to work...

```
npm install --save react-dom
```

changed `index.jsx` content:

```
/** @jsx React.DOM */
'use strict'
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom')
var Hello = require('./Hello')
ReactDOM.render(<Hello />, document.getElementById('content'))
```

And that got it

I'm very new to react, so this may not be the best solution, but it's mine for now.

*edit* : I've since found another, more recent walkthrough (which works)
https://www.twilio.com/blog/2015/08/setting-up-react-for-es6-with-webpack-and-babel-2.html

Answer (score 1):

1. Download the latest React Starter Kit -> https://facebook.github.io/react/downloads.html
2. Use react.js and react-dom.js files on the build folder.
3. Instead of using the "text/jsx" use "text/babel" instead, referencing this minified library -> https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.24/browser.min.js

Here's the full script for your reference

```
<div id="target-container"></div>

<script src="build/react.js"></script>
<script src="build/react-dom.js"></script>
<script src="build/browser.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/babel">
    var MyComponent = React.createClass({
        render: function(){
            return(
                <h1>Sample text</h1>
            );
        }
    });

    ReactDOM.render(
        <MyComponent/>,
        document.getElementById('target-container')
    );
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

you should write `ReactDOM.render` ,instead of `React.render`.

```
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.0/react.js
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.0/react-dom.js
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.23/browser.min.js
```

These three javascript is required